# comparing the contents of two huge text files quickly

Tags: c#, .net

what i'm basically trying to do is compare two HUGE text files and if they match write out a string, i have this written but it's extremely slow.  I was hoping you guys might have a better idea.  In the below example i'm comparing collect[3] splitfound[0]

```
        string[] collectionlist = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\found.txt");
        string[] foundlist = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\collection_export.txt");
        foreach (string found in foundlist)
        {
            string[] spltifound = found.Split('|');
            string matchfound = spltifound[0].Replace(".txt", ""); ;
            foreach (string collect in collectionlist)
            {
                string[] splitcollect = collect.Split('\\');
                string matchcollect = splitcollect[3].Replace(".txt", "");
                if (matchcollect == matchfound)
                {
                    end++;
                   long finaldest = (start - end);
                   Console.WriteLine(finaldest);
                    File.AppendAllText(@"C:\copy.txt", "copy \"" + collect + "\" \"C:\\OUT\\" + spltifound[1] + "\\" + spltifound[0] + ".txt\"\n");
                    break;
                }



            }

        }
```

Sorry for the vagueness guys,

What I'm trying to do is simply say if content from one file exists in another write out a string(the string isn't important, merely the time to find the two comparatives is).    collectionlist is like this:
Apple|Farm

foundlist is like this
C:\cow\horse\turtle.txt
C:\cow\pig\apple.txt

what i'm doing is taking apple from collectionlist, and finding the line that contains apple in foundlist.  Then writing out a basic windows copy batch file.  Sorry for the confusion.

Answer(All credit to Slaks)

```
               string[] foundlist = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\found.txt");
           var collection = File.ReadLines(@"C:\collection_export.txt")
        .ToDictionary(s => s.Split('|')[0].Replace(".txt",""));

        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Copy.txt"))
        {
            foreach (string found in foundlist)
            {
                string[] splitFound = found.Split('\\');
                string matchFound = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(found);

                string collectedLine;
                if (collection.TryGetValue(matchFound,out collectedLine))
                {
                    string[] collectlinesplit = collectedLine.Split('|');
                    end++;
                    long finaldest = (start - end);
                    Console.WriteLine(finaldest);
                    writer.WriteLine("copy \"" + found + "\" \"C:\\O\\" + collectlinesplit[1] + "\\" + collectlinesplit[0] + ".txt\"");
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your code there appears to be doing a lot more than a simple textual comparison, and if these really were huge files, then `ReadAllLines` would fail with an out-of-memory error.  How big are the files?  Are you paging?

Comment: one is about 1million lines and the other is about 200k

Comment: If the 2 text-files have a different amount of lines, then they will never be identical/match, will they ?

Comment: @Frederik: He's not comparing the files for equality, he's parsing a list out of each file, and then computing the intersection of the lists.

Comment: That's a lot of looping.  You seem to expect a very specific format for the text file, so you might want to specify that in your question.  You may also get better performance if you read the file iteratively, rather than all at once.  You're currently waiting for the disk activity to end before starting the intensive memory/cpu part of the code.

Comment: @Mike: How big are the files compared to your free system RAM?

Comment: Why do you assign "found.txt" to collectionlist and "collection_export.txt" to foundlist? That is very confusing.

Comment: Are the files available on the internet somewhere? And how big are they in size, and can you fit them into memory?

Comment: READ THE QUESTION, NOT JUST THE TITLE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Call [File.ReadLines()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503(v=vs.110).aspx) (.NET 4) instead of [ReadAllLines()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines(v=vs.110).aspx) (.NET 2.0).
  `ReadAllLines` needs to build an array to hold the return value, which can be extremely slow for large files.
  If you're not using .Net 4.0, replace it with a StreamReader.
- Build a `Dictionary<string, string>` with the `matchCollect`s (once), then loop through the `foundList` and check whether the HashSet contains `matchFound`.
  This allows you to replace the O(n) inner loop with an O(1) hash check
- Use a StreamWriter instead of calling `AppendText`
- **EDIT**: Call `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension` and the other `Path` methods instead of manually manipulating strings.

For example:

```
var collection = File.ReadLines(@"C:\found.txt")
    .ToDictionary(s => s.Split('\\')[3].Replace(".txt", ""));

using (var writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Copy.txt")) {
    foreach (string found in foundlist) {
        string splitFound = found.Split('|');
        string matchFound = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(found)

        string collectedLine;
        if (collection.TryGetValue(matchFound, collectedLine)) {
            end++;
            long finaldest = (start - end);
            Console.WriteLine(finaldest);
            writer.WriteLine("copy \"" + collectedLine + "\" \"C:\\OUT\\" 
                           + splitFound[1] + "\\" + spltifound[0] + ".txt\"");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try, i made an edit to clarify what i meant, but i think you're 100% on your answer

Comment: it's giving me Error 2 Argument 2 must be passed with the 'out' keyword at string collectedLine;

Comment: so i change to if (collection.TryGetValue(matchFound,out collectedLine)), but while debugging it gave me An item with the same key has already been added.

Comment: @Mike: Your file has duplicate items.  You need to figure out how you want to handle them; you should probably popuulate the dictionary in a second loop and check whether the key already exists.

Comment: I've removed the depulicate lines but what is string collectedLine;
 suppose to be?  Again sorry for the vagueness collectedLine returns null in the code.

Comment: Also, string matchFound = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(found)
the Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension only works on collection, but i think i get the idea

Answer (score 1):

First I'd suggest normalizing both files and putting one of them in a set. This allows you to quickly test whether a specific line is present and reduces the complexity from O(n*n) to O(n).

Also you shouldn't open and close the file every time you write a line:

```
File.AppendAllText(...); // This causes the file to be opened and closed.
```

Open the output file once at the start of the operation, write lines to it, then close it when all lines have been written.

Answer (score 1):

You have a cartesian product, so it makes sense to index one side instead of doing an enhaustive linear search.

Extract the keys from one file and use either a Set or SortedList data structure to hold them.  This will make the lookups much much faster.  (Your overall algorithm will be O(N lg N) instead of O(N**2) )