# C# Compare large text files and write difference

Tags: c#, compare, ienumerable

Simplified question: I have two large files that cannot be stored in memory using a string array, nor can it use the Except method due to that also pushing file data into memory. My goal is to compare two large files and spit out the differences, but I cannot do it by loading even one of the large files into memory. Is there a good streamreader line-by-line solution or other method to do this?

Long question:
I have two files
1. SQLQueryData
2. PhysicalData

SQLQueryData contains names of files listed on the database (Example: `Recording01.wmv` `Audiofile01.wma` `Testrecording.wmv` etc.)

PhysicalData is a directory search on the physical HDD to get the file names that exist there (this should contain the same information as SQLQueryData).

I have purposely deleted files from their directories for this test and made several million test names. SQLQueryData file is 700MB, and PhysicalData is around 650MB.

I first tried a `string[] readfile = file.readalllines` but this causes out of memory errors.

I have also tried `IEnumerable<String>` on both files, however this causes a

> System out of memory error

because it puts both files into memory, which easily eats up about 2GB worth of memory.

My next attempt was to load only ONE file into memory, then use a streamreader to compare a single line of SQLQueryData vs. the string array of PhysicalData, but this also causes an out of memory error.

I have tried embedding a streamreader into another streamreader, but the only methods I see online or examples are IF statements saying if `line1 = line2` of the streamreaders to write that data. I do not want to write `line1=line2`, I need to know if the PhysicalData does not contain SQLQueryData information.

I was thinking of using an extraction method such that if `line1=line2`, extract that line from the file, but I do not know how to write that in code.

Does anyone know anyway to do what I am asking?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [comparing the contents of two huge text files quickly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388355/comparing-the-contents-of-two-huge-text-files-quickly)

Comment: Can you load the files, line by line, into an SQL database. and use SQL to do the comparison?

Comment: Diffing is __not__ a trivial task. Did you think about missing lines and how and when to synch?

Comment: Are the files sorted? Can you replace the query output file with a physical connection to the database? Do you have the ability to add indexes to the database, or is an appropriate index in place? Can you implement a merge sort so that the files can be sorted?

Comment: These files are not sorted, unfortunately. I am making a real world example of a project I must do. We have a database with several file names, not in order, and missing data files on a HDD. My goal is to find out which files are missing and report on those files specifically. Unfortunately since this is real world, we are talking millions of files.

Comment: To commend again: I have already written the directory search and SQL information query, so I can easily push this data to files. Problem is real world files range up to 1GB each. I am trying a mock test using 700MB test files so I cant mess anything up by accident.

So far, I think best example may be extraction but I do not know the code. I can easily write if line=line, but that will give me matches and not differences

Comment: If you have access to the SQL database, this problem is solved easily with a very simple SQL query.

Comment: `StreamReader`s can easily handle multi-GB files; here's [an example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26247952/). If you are getting out-of-memory you're doing something wrong; you have to post your code for us to help.

Comment: @glenebob I guess I did not think about dumping the filenames to a temp table. That might work best.

Comment: @DourHighArch
If you read the post, it only shows out of memory when attempting to use a string array or IEnumerable.

I clearly stated I used a streamreader within a streamreader and recieved no problems, my only issue now is either extracting the matching data out of the files or somehow writting the lines that do not have a match inside the individual file once the stream reader has finished reading the compared file completely.

Answer (score 0):

To compare lines sequentially the files must be already sorted. To sort large files, you could use http://classCentric.com/SortHugeFile. The following snippet is part of the http://classCentric.com/SortedDiff tool which handles edge cases, supports regular expression extraction, and allows numeric comparison. SortedDiff.cs compares a testFile to a masterFile and outputs the files mentioned in the first 3 lines. Full source code is downloadable.

```
TextWriter twTest = new StreamWriter("inTestFile.txt");
TextWriter twMaster = new StreamWriter("inMasterFile.txt");
TextWriter twInBoth = new StreamWriter("inBothFiles.txt");
using (StreamReader tr = new StreamReader(testFile))
{
    using (StreamReader mr = new StreamReader(masterFile))
    {
        mLine = mr.ReadLine();

        while ((tLine = tr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (mLine != null) break;
            //-1: tLine < mLine; 1: tLine > mLine
            comp = String.Compare(tPart, mPart, oStringComparison);

            //while value in test file < that in master, increment test's pointer to process next tLine
            if (comp < 0)
            {
                twTest.WriteLine(tLine);
                continue;
            }

            //while value in test file > that in master, increment master's pointer to process next mLine
            while (comp > 0)
            {
                twMaster.WriteLine(mLine);

                mLine = mr.ReadLine();
                if (mLine == null) break;

                comp = String.Compare(tPart, mPart, oStringComparison);
            }

            if (comp == 0)
            {
                twInBoth.WriteLine(mLine);
                mLine = mr.ReadLine();
            }
            else //comp must be < 0 since "copm > 0" is handled in while & "== 0" after that
            {
                twTest.WriteLine(tLine);
            }
        }//while
    }//using
}//using
```

Answer (score -1):

A few points:

1. For this to perform even close to acceptably, you are going to need to sort the contents first to enable binary search.  You can achieve this by making an algorithm that reads the file from front to back and swaps any two consecutive lines if they are out of order, repeating until sorted.  Or you can use this maybe: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/285123/Sorting-Huge-Text-Files

   Only one of the files needs to be sorted.
2. If the format of the files is not fixed-width (same byte count per line), then you are going to need to create an index telling you the starting byte offset of each line.  The index should be held in memory if possible (a List or long[] is ideal here if you want to have files > 4GB in size)
3. For the best performance, I recommend using a MemoryMappedFile: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile(v=vs.110).aspx for accessing both files you are reading. The View should be at least the size of the largest line.
4. Once you have sorted one of the files (and indexed, if not fixed width, both files), start looping through your long[] for the unsorted file, read in the line at that byte offset, and then use binary search to find the corresponding entry in the other file.  If nothing is found, write the difference out to a third file, your difference file.

Comment: This may work. I will try it now. An arrey of numbers would be less than an array of file names (they use GUID's so file names are like 012093-12341-xasd-recordingname.wmv)

Comment: If you go this route, there's no need to do any binary searching, and therefore no need for a line offset index. You can sort both files, and then run a merge operation to find the matches and mismatches. That approach should be faster and simpler.

Comment: @glenebob 
You have been pretty helpful. I used a SQL method like above, but it took over an hour to complete. I need to find some way to streamline this as the real world files could be as large as 2-4GB. The SQL method would take ages, if it would complete at all.

I thought about breaking down the file sizes into 100MB files and make multiple files instead of one large one, but I still don't know how to compare against all files because now data is split into multiple locations

Comment: Are your tables indexed? Not that they need to be, the SQL server could use the same approach as above - sort both sets, and merge, which should be faster than index look ups. What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: @glenebob
Yes, I indexed the table right after it was created. It still took about an hour. I tried to make a "primary key" index but it failed due to table being full, I also tried to use a flag bit (0 for audio, 1 for video) in an effort to help it search faster, but the sheer amount of files filled the tempdb.

Answer (score -2):

See StreamReader's ReadLine method:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline(v=vs.110).aspx

Also see some tutorials here and especially note the "using" there (nicer to read than using try/finally and Dispose explicitly):

http://www.dotnetperls.com/streamreader

Comment: Thank, but I have already read these. Like my post stated, I used a streamreader to begin reading the lines, but the examples provided in other threads are writing lines that equal one another. Currently, I am approaching this with an extraction mindset, but I am unsure of how to code it in such a way as if line1=line2 then delete line2 from the file.

I am also unsure of how to make it say if it reads the full file length and does not find a match, to write that specific line.

Either method should work, but I cannot find a solution

Comment: Obviously you have to spit out a third file for "deleting" something. For checking if a line exists at the next part, you'll have to reparse the files multiple times. That is unless you want to use more temporary storage (in memory and/or in disk), like building octree or some index out of the original files, then work with that and delete the temp stuff when finished